# Angularjs preventing validation of input fields inside dynamically hidden div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a directive to dynamically hide input field.Rules are coming from the database.If  all the divs within a div are hidden then paren div's visibility is also set to none. Problem is hidden elements are not passing validation.
This is my code

```
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 0,
    terminal: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var unwatch = scope.$watchCollection('fieldRules', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (scope.fieldRules != undefined && scope.fieldRules.length > 0) {
                var elem = $(element);
                var rule = $filter('filter')(scope.fieldRules, { FieldKey: attrs.key })[0];
                if (element.is('div')) {
                    if (!rule.IsVisible) {
                        attrs.$set('ngHide', true);
                        //attrs.$set('ngIf', false);
                        var lastDiv = elem.siblings('div').last();
                        lastDiv.addClass('field-alignment');
                    }
                    else {
                        attrs.$set('ngShow', true);
                        //attrs.$set('ngIf', true);
                    }
                    var parentDiv = elem.closest('div.form-group')
                    if (parentDiv.find('div.input-group[ng-hide!=true]').length === 0){
                        parentDiv.hide();
                    }
                }

                attrs.$set('fieldRule', null);
                $compile(element)(scope);

            }
        })
    }    

 }
```

One of the solutions on stackoverflow advised to use ng-if but it also did not work.

> **Edit**
>   I want angular to bypass validation for input fields which are inside a hidden div(these input fields are required means they contain attribute ng-required=true ). I have also removed the unnecessary code.

This is my html

```
<div field-rule data-key="minhourlyrate" class="input-group erorinner" style="width: 48%;float: left;" ng-class="{invalidField:checkFieldValidity(signupForm.minhourlyrate)}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
<input id="txtMinHourlyRate" min="0" max="100" type="number"   name="minhourlyrate" ng-model="user.MinHourlyRate" class="form-control" placeholder="Min" autofocus="" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" ng-required="true">
```

All I'm trying to do is hide an input field along with the div containing it through a directive.An idea to write a new directive to solve the problem is also very welcome.

Comment: is ngRequired being set correctly for elements which are hidden?

Comment: in the html ngRequired is true for these hidden elements

Comment: anoyone. plz help. I;m totally stuck.I think there is somrthing wrong with my directive.All I'm trying to do is hide an input field along with the div containing it through a directive.

Comment: You need to set ng-required to false for the hidden elements.  Ng-required is what triggers the validations.